# Is there any way I can add alternative key binding to a feature in compiz?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, compiz

I was wondering is there any way to add additional, alternative key binding to a particular feature in compiz?

I am using Wall plugin and on my ThinkPad it is convenient to switch between horizontal workspaces with media buttons for browser navigation. But there just two of them, so I have to use completely different combinations to switch between workspaces vertically and that would very helpful if I can also use similar kind of combination to switch horizontally as well *in addition* to those media buttons.

Is there a way maybe to send a message to the compiz to execute particular command? That would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I like to use [CCSM](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM) (CompizConfig Settings Manager).

Comment: It allows to set up just **one** key shortcut for any particular feature. And I want **two** different ones that will trigger the same action.

Comment: Its been a while since I used it, but I recall it having a custom section that allowed you to choose commands and choose shortcuts for those commands.  To make a two shortcuts point to the same command, you'd have to have two different lines that do the same command each with a different shortcut.  I'll don't have access to CCSM at the moment, I'll have to try it later.

Answer (score 0):

You can send messages to compiz using the Compiz Dbus plugin.

http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Dbus

A Python script is available to download from that page which vastly simplifies things, or you can use pycompiz:

http://code.google.com/p/pycompiz/

Then you can bind the additional commands to keyboard shortcuts in CCSM, or your DE's usual method.

However I did find some limitations to this method; in the end I achieved what I wanted using binds to xdotool commands simulating the original Compiz keypress.